# parsing using loop and assigning row numbers to file

Tags: linux, shell-script, centos, c, sparse-files

It is a bit complicated. i have a configuration file. it looks something like this.

```
customer="airtel"
model_name=fast
programmer_typ_of="dev"
```

Now the 1st column contains all the keys and whatever is after the `=` is the value of each key. It is like this format:

```
key=value
```

How can I write a function where it will call such a file and store each key and value to two separate arrays where same position of each array will contain corresponding key and value. Please note that I cannot use the name of my key in the function anywhere neither I can grep using the exact key name. Alternatively I have thought of a way of solving this by assigning row numbers to the configuration file and the 'cut' each key and value pairs based on using `grep` in a loop to find the individual row numbers. something like this :

```
function parse() {
    i=0
    declare -a arr1
    declare -a arr2
    cat -n model.conf    #assigns row numbers to model.conf

    while true; do
    var1=$(cat model.conf |  grep ^$i | cut -d '=' -f1)    #gets the key and stores it in variable var1
    var2=$(cat model.conf |  grep ^$i | cut -d '=' -f2)    #gets the value and stores it in variable var2
    arr1[$i]=$var1    #array containing keys
    arr2[$i]=$var2    #array containing values
    i=$(( $i  + 1 ))
    done
}
```

If you could tell me what is wrong in this function or if you could suggest some other method of getting separate key value pairs in different arrays.

Comment: How many keys, and for what do you need to parse this? to feed other program? Only once, or many times? How often?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro : Thank you for your comment. there can be a number of keys but for each key there would be only one value. yes it would be needed to feed other program. it would be many times.

Comment: If it is very often, it would be more interesting using a key store engine like redis or memcached than using intermediate files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With awk:

```
eval $(awk -F= -v i=0 '{print "arr1["i"]="$1";arr2["i"]="$2;i++}' model.conf)
```

With `=` as field seperator and variable `i` with initial value `0`, `awk` will print `"arr1["i"]="$1";arr2["i"]="$2` for each line where `$1` will have the key and `$1` will have the value and increment `i` for each line.

`awk -F= -v i=0 '{print "arr1["i"]="$1";arr2["i"]="$2;i++}' model.conf` O/P:

```
arr1[0]=customer;arr2[0]="airtel"
arr1[1]=model_name;arr2[1]=fast
arr1[3]=programmer_typ_of;arr2[3]="dev"
```

Then use `eval` on awk output to assign arrays.

Comment: thank you for your comment. as i am new to awk, could you kindly explain the command in details. could you also provide examples to explain if needed.

Comment: Edited the answer. I hope this will help.

Comment: could you kindly explain this part arr1["i"]="$1" and arr2["i"]="$2. what is the function on $1 and $2, how is it taking each key and value everytime into account for each line. just not particularly clear about this. thank you.

Comment: awk reads files line by line. So for 1st line `i` will be `0`. `i` incremtn by `1` for each line.  `$1` and `$2` are used to represent 1st and 2nd field.

Comment: I recommend you read `awk` basic tutorial to get more info.

Comment: is there any way i can declare these arrays globally and then call them in another function?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772036/pass-all-variables-from-one-shellscript-to-another

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it directly using the bash shell's built-in `read` function, by setting the field separator to `=`

```
while IFS== read -r name value; do 
  arr1+=("$name")
  arr2+=("$value") 
done < model.conf
```

The arrays will be zero indexed by default, i.e.

```
$ echo "${arr1[0]}"
customer
$ echo "${arr2[0]}"
"airtel"
```

---

Since variables (including arrays) have global scope unless explicitly declared as `local`, you may put the parse loop in a function if you wish. To illustrate:

```
#!/bin/bash

function parse() {
while IFS== read -r name value; do
  arr1+=("$name")
  arr2+=("$value")
done < model.conf
}

# call the function to extract key=value pairs from file to arrays
parse

# now we can use the arrays e.g.
for i in "${!arr1[@]}"; do
  printf 'key: %s\tvalue: %s\n' "${arr1[$i]}" "${arr2[$i]}"
done
```

Result

```
key: customer   value: "airtel"
key: model_name value: fast
key: programmer_typ_of  value: "dev"
```

Comment: is there anyway i can declare these arrays globally and then call them in another function?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal AFAIK bash variables have global scope unless explicitly declared as `local`, so that should "just work"

Comment: could you kindly explain the above code with an example. it would actually help a lot.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal please see edit

Comment: i am just being able to print the values of the two arrays in that format. i am not being able to use the value of the arrays in that function like passing a parameter in that function and then searching that value in both the arrays.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal sorry, I don't understand what you want: you asked for a way to *"store each key and value to two separate arrays where same position of each array will contain corresponding key and value"* and that's what I believe I have have shown. If you have a different requirement then I suggest you ask it in a separate question.